# How to integrate Unity3d in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, eclipse-plugin, unityscript

I am unable to integrate Unity3d with Eclipse IDE. I want to create a game in Android with Unity3d.

I referred to [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html), but I am unable to get perfect idea on how to integrate it.

Can anyone please provide me steps on how to integrate it?

Comment: @dd619 i install unity3d from [here](http://unity3d.com/unity/)

Comment: are you able to setup project in unity?

Comment: Why do you need to use Eclipse? Android APK files can be built directly in Unity3d.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use Eclipse with Unity rather than MonoDevelop or Visual Studio which are supported out of the box?

Comment: For Unity to build the (Android) project, you do need to install the Android SDK, as this will allow you to build and push to an Android device in one step.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need eclipse for making android game. Visit this link for learning unity

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules

You need eclipse or android studio when you will make android plugin for unity

Answer (score 0):

From inside unity Press file/Build settings/android/then check the google android project chekbox and select the folder where you want to export the project.

after that unity will export your project as android project.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity:
File -> Build Settings. 
Platform, Select Android. 
Check the checkBox "Google Android Project".
Build it.

You will get a Google Android Project
Then open it with Eclipse